# Not getting link for creating firestore index

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my flutter app, I am running a firestore query like this :

```
final userDoc = await _firestore.userDocument();
    final name = nameStr.toUpperCase();
    yield* userDoc.firestore
        .collectionGroup('persons')
        .where(
          'name',
          isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: name,
          isLessThan: name.substring(0, name.length - 1) +
              String.fromCharCode(
                  name.codeUnitAt(name.length - 1) + 1),
        )
        .snapshots()
        .map(
          (snapshot) => right<Failure, List<Person>>(
            snapshot.docs
                .map((doc) => Dto.fromFirestore(doc).toDomain())
                .toList(),
          ),
        )
        .onErrorReturnWith((e) {
      if (e is PlatformException && e.message.contains('PERMISSION_DENIED')) {
        return ...;
      } else {
        print(e.toString());
        return ...;
      }
    });
```

It shows the following error :

> I/flutter (27416): [cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase console.

Probably because of the `where`, I need to add index in console, so in the error message I am expecting an url to add index, but not getting it. I tried `adb logcat`, not even there.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation for collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) you will find at the bottom:

"Before using a collection group query, you must create an index that supports your collection group query. You can create an index through an error message, the console, or the Firebase CLI.

For the web and mobile SDKs, you must also create rules that allow your collection group queries."

So you will need to [create security rules for your collection group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_collection_groups) and then, if you can't get the error message with `adb logcat`, you will need to manually create the index either through the [Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#use_the_firebase_console) or the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#use_the_firebase_cli).

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your `where` statements.

```
.collectionGroup('persons')
        .where(
          'name',
          isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: name)
         .where('name', isLessThan: name.substring(0, name.length - 1) +
              String.fromCharCode(
                  name.codeUnitAt(name.length - 1) + 1),
        )
```

Comment: Tried your answer, but still not getting the desired link!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?